# How do I set up a configured environment from a cloned repo?

Tags: python, environment

I cloned a repo and I'm trying to run my tests and i'm getting an interpreter error:

```
Interpreter path does not exist: C:\Users\username\Source\Repos\citcodownloader\env\Scripts\python.exe
```

The project downloaded a `.sln`, solutions view that I opened it with and I thought it set up my enviornment but it doesn't seem to be doing so. Not sure what to do from here.

Answer (score 0):

The best thing you can do is create a (or use an existing) [Virtual Environment](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html). It looks like your program is looking for one in the folder "env". Try this:

1. Open a terminal (Windows key + R, then type cmd and press enter)
2. Navigate to your repo folder using `chdir C:\path\to\your\repo`
3. Run the command `env\Scripts\activate.bat` (if there is no folder called "env" in your repo, use my instructions below)
4. Try running your program again.

I hope this helps, post a comment if it doesn't and I'll add as much detail or explanation as you need. Good luck!

**For Googlers or people who that doesn't help, look for these files in your repo:**

- `requirements.txt` (a list of plugins you need to set up a virtual environment)
- `venv/` (folder containing a virtual environment)

**Solution**

1. If a folder named 'venv' or 'virtualenv' does **NOT** exist,
   run this command to create it: `python -m venv venv` (or for Python 3: `python3 -m venv venv`). If it does exist, move forward.
2. You have a virtual environment! Now enter into it using: `source venv/bin/active` (on Unix or OSX, see the link above for the Windows command).
3. If `requirements.txt` is there, run this command next: `pip install -r requirements.txt`. If not, move forward.
4. Run the program again (via whatever method the repo says you should use). If you get 'error: module is not installed' use the command `pip install moduleNameHere` and run the program again.
5. Keep doing step 4 for each missing module, once the program is working use `pip freeze > requirements.txt` to create a requirements file and save yourself the headache next time. :)